# Spring security and custom AuthenticationFilter with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have custom authentication filter which creates `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` and stores it in security context. This all works fine. Here is the config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SsoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private SsoAuthenticationFilter ssoAuthenticationFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(ssoAuthenticationFilter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Now my `ssoAuthenticationFilter` is part of the `FilterChainProxy`, on the right position. Smooth.

But as the `ssoAuthenticationFilter` is `Filter` it gets picked up by Boot and included as a filter. So my filter chain really looks like:

- ssoAuthenticationFilter (included because being `Filter`)
- filterChainProxy (spring autoconfiguration)

  - ...
  - SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  - ssoAuthenticationFilter (included by `http.addFilterAfter(...)`)
  - ...
- some other filters

Obviously I would like to get rid of the autoregistration of the `ssoAuthenticationFilter` here (the first one listed).

Any tips much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2 choices:

1. Add a `FilterRegistrationBean` `@Bean` with your filter bean as its target filter and mark it as enabled=false
2. Don't create a `@Bean` definition for your filter (normally that's what I do, but YMMV since you might depend on autowiring or something to get it working)

Comment: Are there any plans to converge the Spring Security filter configuration with the Spring Boot way of doing it? I'd love to be able to set the order of my servlet filters, including being able to put one before the security filters without having to mess with the `HttpSecurity`

Comment: Don't think I understand that one (and it doesn't seem to add anything to the answer). Anyway, you can't do security filters as ordered beans because there can be multiple filter chains in one context.