# PreAuthorize and custom AuthenticationFilter with Spring boot

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I have custom authentication filter which creates PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken and stores it in security context. The filter works fine, it creates the token with the appropriate granted authorities "ROLE_user" and "ROLE_adminuser". Here's my config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        X509AuthenticationFilter filter = new X509AuthenticationFilter()
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager())
        http.addFilterAfter(filter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean()
        X509AuthenticationFilter filter = new X509AuthenticationFilter()
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager())
        registrationBean.setFilter(filter)
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false)
        return registrationBean
    }
```

I'm inserting the Filter before the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter as mentioned in: [Spring security and custom AuthenticationFilter with Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568261/spring-security-and-custom-authenticationfilter-with-spring-boot).

This seems to work fine, however, when I attempt to add a PreAuthorize annotation to my controller method, like so:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/security")
class SecurityController {

    @RequestMapping("/authenticate")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_user')")
    @ResponseBody
        ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(HttpServletRequest request,     Principal principal) {
        println "authenticate: " +     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()

        return new ResponseEntity<String>(getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(request), HttpStatus.OK)
    }
```

I get a 404 error. If I comment out the PreAuthorize annotation the method call works and you can see that I print out the authentication information and the authenticated user has ROLE_user and ROLE_adminuser for its granted authorities. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the print out of the authentication object in the principal when "PreAuthorize" is commented out:

> authenticate:
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken@817a0240:
>   Principal:
>   org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl@c279eab8:
>   Dn: uid=1,ou=people,dc=cdpe,dc=mil; Username: xxxx@gmail.com;
>   Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true;
>   CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted
>   Authorities: ROLE_adminuser, ROLE_user; Credentials: [PROTECTED];
>   Authenticated: true; Details:
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e:
>   RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities:
>   ROLE_adminuser, ROLE_user authorities: [ROLE_adminuser, ROLE_user]

Update: I've made a little progress. I added the proxyTargetClass  to the following annotation:

```
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Now I'm getting 403 Forbidden returns when I call my method. I have no idea what that is doing.

Comment: If this is Spring Security 4 or higher, than `hasRole()` method accepts role without `ROLE_` prefix. So your check should be some think like this `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('user')")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring Security has always been tedious to configure, and the only foolproof ways are:

- either being an expert on it and be prepared to look in the sources and then you can do hard things *by hand*
- or use as much as possible of what is provided by framework using examples from the documentation whenever possible

For the configuration of an `X509AuthenticationFilter`, `HttpSecurity` javadoc gives the method `x509` with following example (adapted to your config - see javadoc for original one) :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {    

     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
             .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
             // Example x509() configuration
             .x509();
     }
 }
```

with following indication: method returns the `X509Configurer` for further customizations.

Unless you have a good reason to do differently (and if it is the case please say it) I strongly advise you to stick to that method.

But it is really a bad idea to use pre-post annotation on a controller, for what could be done directly in `HttpSecurity` configuration. It forced you to use `proxyTargetClass = true`.

Pre and post annotation are normally applied to methods of service layer what do not require `proxyTargetClass=true` since services are normally wired to controller through interfaces allowing JDK proxying.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. For this example I'm being forced to re-use an already working Spring security custom filter. I'm just trying to get it to work in the spring-boot context.

Adding the `proxyTargetClass = true` to the above code seems to have fixed the problem.