# Using security annotation and secure by default

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using Spring-security in a Spring-boot appplication. By default, all methods are restricted to authenticated users thanks to this configuration :

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Now, I would like to mark some urls as public. I could do it with ant matchers but I would prefer to be able to directly mark the relevant methods with an annotation.

I saw that some `@PreAuthorize` annotation exist but I could have it work only if I remove those lines from the configuration :

```
      .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
```

This forces me to annotate manually every method that I want to secure with this annotation :

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
```

This is highly dangerous because every forgotten url will be publicly accessible by default. Is there a way to make every url accessible to authenticated users by default and open some urls with

```
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
```

Also, I saw in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775038/preauthorize-and-custom-authenticationfilter-with-spring-boot) that the OP was answered :

> But it is really a bad idea to use pre-post annotation on a controller, for what could be done directly in HttpSecurity configuration. It forced you to use `proxyTargetClass = true`.

What is wrong with that? (Also, I did not need to use `proxyTargetClass = true`)

Comment: Add `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` on every class and override on the method level if it is required

Comment: @AliDehghani Seems reasonable as I can include this in a template for every Controller, thanks.